# Почему python обращается к анаконде?

Tags: python, django, anaconda

Изучаю Django, выполняю команду и вылазит вот такая ошибка. Видимо Django должен напрямую что-то из питона брать, но лезет в анаконду, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы django запускаете?

Comment: @gil9red Не понял вопроса, если Вы имели ввиду проект, то   через runserver